# Create Hive table from ORC without specifying schema

Tags: apache-spark, hive, orc, hive-metastore

Is there a simple way to create Hive External table without specifying the columns/schema (ORC already defines the schema).

I can only think on a Spark job that reads the file and creates the table.

Comment: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive

Comment: Can it be used on top of S3 and GCP Cloud Storage ?

Comment: Also can it discover new partitions and schema changes similar to AWS Glue crawler?